# ZFS Permanant errors dectected in the following files (<0xf49a>:<0x390aff>)

Tags: zfs, truenas, raidz

I had to replace one of my hard drives in our storage array and now I'm getting the following message

```
 pool: vol0
 state: ONLINE

status: One or more devices has experienced an error resulting in data
    corruption.  Applications may be affected.

action: Restore the file in question if possible.  Otherwise restore the
    entire pool from backup.

see: http://illumos.org/msg/ZFS-8000-8A
  scan: resilvered 6.06T in 31h40m with 1 errors on Wed Nov  1 16:38:43 2017
```

errors: Permanent errors have been detected in the following files:

```
    <0xf49a>:<0x390aff>
```

The volume is online. From doing some research it looks like this might be corrupt metadata - is it anything I can do or anything I should be worried about?

More to the point, if this isn't anything to worry about is it easy enough to clear the error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The `<0xf49a>:<0x390aff>` id tells you that this error doesn't map to any existing file or zvol. It definitely was in the past, but now either the file is deleted or the zvol is. This error will be gone on the next `scrub`.

From my point of view this has nothing to do with corrupt metadata, as the consequences would be more rough with it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see how we go after the next scrub! Given me a little confidence the situation isn't as bad as it looks :)

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/a/846758/250029 in case a subsequent `zpool scrub` does not clear those hex errors.